# Python, поэлементое объединение двух списков

Tags: python

Есть:\

```py
a = ['a', 'b' , 'c']
b = ['d', 'e']
```

надо:

```py
с = ['ad', 'ae', 'bd', 'be', 'cd', 'ce]
```

Одна проблема в списках по 20 тысяч элементов и в конечном итоге должно получится почти пол миллиарда элементов.

Comment: Полмиллиарда не получится, у вас 3 x 2 элементов. ))

Comment: [гляньте вот сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/10562663), а вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45378609/10562663) можно на графике посмотреть насколько itertools менее эффективен

Comment: И всё же - зачем это всё? Так то да, если будет работать генератор, с выводом которого вы что-то будете делать, то вообще не проблема.

Comment: А по памяти - порядка 20Гб будет на выходе

Comment: В виде файла, кстати, всего то порядка 1Гб получится, ерунда вообще )

Comment: Тоже спрошу - **зачем** нужны результаты объединения в свете `остановил на том моменте когда файл перевалил за 10gb` и т.п. ??? Как вы собираетесь их использовать?

Answer (score 2):

Без лишних заморочек, через `for`'ы

```py
a = ['a', 'b' , 'c']
b = ['d', 'e']
result=[]
for i in a:
    for k in b:
        result.append(i+k)
print(result)
```

Вывод

```
['ad', 'ae', 'bd', 'be', 'cd', 'ce']
```

Попробуйте так

```py
from itertools import product

c = []
for i in map("".join, product(a, b)):
    c.append(i)
```

**UPD**

Добавлю тест

```py
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import product

import random
import string

st = string.ascii_letters
a1 = [random.choice(st) for i in range(7500)]
a2 = [random.choice(st) for i in range(7500)]
start_time = datetime.now()

c = []
for i in map("".join, product(a1, a2)):
    c.append(i)

print(datetime.now() - start_time)
print(len(c))
```

Вывод

```
0:00:32.137720
56250000
```

c 15000 элементов в каждом массиве

```
0:02:07.818000
211630648
```

с 20000 элементов спокойно

```
0:03:58.849912
400000000
```

Рухнула на 40000

Comment: Мне кажется, при цифрах, которые были указаны в условии, эти циклы будут выполнять невероятно долго, если вообще выполнятся

Comment: в каждом из списков по 20 тысяч элементов, памяти тупо не хватает))

Comment: memoryerror вылетает ?

Comment: да memoryerror )

Comment: Не надо всё в список собирать. Обрабатывайте в цикле: `for p in map(''.join, product(a, b)): ...`. `product` - итератор, он не будет создавать никаких элементов пока вы не начнёте работать с ними в цикле. Цикл начнётся мгновенно и будет продолжаться пока хватит вашего терпения.

Comment: даже через product, на объединение уйдет минимум 1 час, это если не брать загруженность памяти)потому что я уже пробовал и тупо все зависает и memoryerror вылетает)

Comment: @Frank есть входные данные в открытом доступе?

Comment: `product` ничего не объединяет. Вы у него в цикле просите следующий элемент, он его возвращает. Память - константа, время пропоционально числу итераций цикла.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy сижу, туплю. Понятно, что product вернет итератор, но все равно собрать лист надо по условию

Comment: @Dmitry нет, нету

Comment: @Frank [Такого плана функции](https://github.com/a904guy/itertools_product_bigData) пробовали?

Comment: На моём компе `for` для 10000 * 10000 элементов выполнялся 43 секунды (печать в консоль). За четыре минуты вы породите полмиллиарда строк. Памяти вообще не нужно.

Comment: На моем компе пробовал со списками в 35к и 12к, вылетает memoryerror, думал может дело в jupyter, попробовал через cmd, все равно ошибка

Comment: @Frank согласен, надо другое решение искать. Все равно тяжко машинке, это видно

Comment: @Dmitry как найду - отпишусь)

Comment: @Frank я думаю надо смотреть в сторону pandas или scipy

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно получить список из объединённых букв, то можете попробовать смесь из `itertools` и `map(''.join, получившиеся комбинации)` — последняя функция как раз объединит все комбинации в строки, а их — в список.

```py
import itertools

a = ['a', 'b' , 'c']
b = ['d', 'e']

print(list(map(''.join, itertools.product(a, b))))
# ['ad', 'ae', 'bd', 'be', 'cd', 'ce']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = list(range(1, 100000))
b = list(range(1, 100000))

with open('result.txt', 'a') as file:
    for el_a in a:
        for el_b in b:
            file.write(f'{el_a}{el_b}\n')
```

Comment: Таким образом получим огроменный txt, который не откроешь, кто знает оптимизацию лучше ?

Comment: Зачем записывать что-то в файл, если вы быстро порождаете эти данные в цикле?

Comment: остановил на том моменте когда файл перевалил за 10gb)